# angular validation - ng-dirty and required is not showing

Tags: angularjs

i have a small angular validation where i want an error to show if a textfield is dirty and another error if it is required.

**my html:**

```
<form name="someform1" controller="validateCtrl" novalidate>
  <input ng-model="namefld" type="text" required/>
  <span ng-show="someform1.namefld.$dirty">pls enter name field</span>
  <span ng-show="someform1.namefld.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
</form>
```

i have set the **controller** like this:

```
var myapp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.namefld = 'John Doe';
    $scope.email = 'john.doe@gmail.com';
});
```

"*myApp*" is defined in the `<html>` tag so that is not the problem. I am missing something and am new to angular, pls guide what i am doing wrong.

Comment: You need to add `name` attribute to your `input` tag. E.g. `<input ng-model="namefld" type="text" name="namefld" required />`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `name` to the input too. As you have it set up now `$dirty` will only work on the form itself not on each individual input, you need to add a name to the inputs for that

Answer (score 0):

[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YOthCCrz8rha4c6nhQwl?p=preview)

You are missing `name='namefld'`

```
<input ng-model="namefld" name='namefld' type="text" required/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular form validation works based on the name of the form and the form inputs. In your case you have specified the name of the form but not the input element. Add the `name="namefld"` to the input element and it will work.

```
<form name="someform1" novalidate>
  <input ng-model="namefld" name="namefld" type="text" required/>
  <span ng-show="someform1.namefld.$dirty">pls enter name field</span>
  <span ng-show="someform1.namefld.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
</form>
```

See a working [JSbin](https://jsbin.com/keraje/edit?html,js,console,output) for same, that I have created